# Add an outline to a crcular png in html css

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I want to add a 4px white circular border around this circular png.

http://oi45.tinypic.com/n6uo8o.jpg

I could not do this in the picture itself because i want a hover effect later. 
Please help! Thanks.

Comment: That PNG isn't circular, and it isn't a PNG.

Comment: @robertc, it actually is a png. opening it up in photoshop shows transparency, and a correct file type.

Comment: @JamesRasmussen Just because pixels are transparent doesn't mean they're not part of the image.

Comment: @robertc .jpg doesn't support transparency, so this is definitely not a .jpg. If you'd look at it in photoshop, you'd see .png as the filetype, and transparency, which .jpg doesn't support.

Comment: @JamesRasmussen Looking at it in Photoshop, [it's still a square image](http://imgur.com/TyRfQ)

Comment: @robertc Well of course the image itself is square. Unless you had an svg or some other vector file type, you're not going to get anything BUT a square or rectangular image with ANY image filetype, not just .jpg or .png. The image itself is a png. It's square (obviously). However, it is still possible to apply a border around the image that is circular, as the answers below have shown.

Comment: @JamesRasmussen I never said it wasn't, I just said, in addition to getting confused by the file extension on the URL, that the PNG isn't circular.

Comment: sorry tinypic.com  makes my png a square img

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<img src="http://oi45.tinypic.com/n6uo8o.jpg" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
width:180px;
height:180px;        
border:2px solid red;
border-radius:90px;   
}
```

this CSS will have no white space betweed the "face" and the border:

```
img {
width:180px;
height:180px;        
border:5px solid red;
border-radius:90px;
background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ue9sG/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a circular element using CSS as follows:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  border:1px solid #000;
}​
```

width and height could vary but should be equal to each other to use `border-radius:50%;` or you'll need to change the `border-radius` property according to your needs [as in the answer by OP].

here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcdUC/)

Also to learn more about CSS circles click this [link](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles)

Answer (score 2):

Apply the `border-radius` property to your object in question.

Property syntax:

```
border-*-*-radius: [ <length> | <%> ] [ <length> | <%> ]?
```

Example:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

Read more about the border-radius property, [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).